# jquery-datatables-rails. responsive extention and mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I use:

```
rails 4.2.1 
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', '~>0.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
```

Responsive extra works at normal browser window, when I resize. But doesn't work on mobile phones or in mobile view in chrome.

I'm was trying:

1. disable bootstrap-sass
2. change responsive extra from 1.0.5 to 1.0.7

when I try to look [table](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) from datatables.net in mobile mode, everything is OK
Screenshots [here](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/issues/200)

Comment: Add this in your HTML after `<head>` -  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your HTML after `<head>` tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

> A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
> ```
>
> The `width` property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like `width=600` or to the special value `device-width` value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding `height` and `device-height` values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable` properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.